# Calling a subclass method. Pointer vs non-pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

I have the following code:

**main.hxx:**

```
#include <iostream>

class Base{
public:
    Base() {}
    ~Base() {}

    virtual void whoAreYou() { std::cout << "I am base!" << std::endl;}
};

class Sub : public Base{
public:
    Sub() {}
    ~Sub() {}

    virtual void whoAreYou() { std::cout << "I am Sub!" << std::endl;}
};

class Factory {

public:
    static Base getBase() { return Base(); }

    static Base* getBasePtr() { return new Base(); }

    static Base getSub() { return Sub(); }

    static Base* getSubPtr() { return new Sub(); }
};
```

**main.cxx**

```
#include "main.hxx"

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    // Non pointers
    Factory::getBase().whoAreYou();
    Factory::getSub().whoAreYou();

    // Pointers
    Base* basePtr = Factory::getBasePtr();
    Base* subPtr = Factory::getSubPtr();
    basePtr->whoAreYou();
    subPtr->whoAreYou();

    delete basePtr, subPtr;

    return 0;
}
```

When run, it prints the following:

```
I am base!
I am base!
I am base!
I am Sub!
```

I was expecting "Factory::getSub().whoAreYou();" to print "I am Sub!". Is it because when not using a pointer it gets casted to a Base?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was expecting `Factory::getSub().whoAreYou();` to print "I am Sub!".

No, the function returns a `Base`, so a `Base` is what you get.

> Is it because when not using a pointer it gets casted to a Base?

Yes (although the word is "converted" not "casted" - a cast is an explicit conversion, and this conversion is implicit). This is sometimes called "slicing", since the derived-class part of the object is "sliced off" when it's copied.

Also, beware that the following:

```
delete basePtr, subPtr;
```

only deletes `subPtr`. You need a separate delete expression for each. You also need a virtual destructor in `Base` to safely delete `subPtr`.

Answer (score 2):

This line creates a `Sub` then call `Base` default copy constructor to create a instance of `Base` from a the instance `Sub`:

```
static Base getSub() { return Sub(); }
```

Hence your log.

More generaly a `Base` is a `Base` instance, whereas `Base*` is a pointer on a `Base` instance or an object that inherits `Base`.